# Dynamically pop up table with button click - iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, dynamic, cell

I am having 1 button in my view. I want to pop-up table on button click on the same view and make it disappear when I click on cell.
For that ajax is required?
Is there another option for this?

Comment: pop up table means tableview right?

Comment: @Shubhank - yes.I want that it will be appeared with some effects.

Comment: I believe you want something similar to UIpopView found in iPad having a tableview. Check this git.. https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover

Comment: Is there any other way?

Comment: that code is too long and complex.I want to open table with some static height and width.Can you help me?

Comment: i understand it is not easy to integrate and do yourself..but you can get a lot go advanced as well visual features for very less code..the easy way is the answer by @parth..but that won't look good .. the popover git link i gave is what will look good as a new tableview pop up.

Comment: if you want to present a full screen table view.. then you can just load a new view with a tableview that will be the easy way..and also in that case parth answer is also good..my answer is best if you want the table view to cover only small portion of view

Comment: - yes, I have gone through that git code you have given . I will refer it.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

NO, Ajax is not required.

Make the table view `hidden` property `FALSE` and put it inside UIView Animation block to present or show table view.

Also if you hide it when table view is clicked, then you just need to hide or set tableview `hidden` property to `TRUE` on `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method for table view.

Also you need to study `UIView Animations` to learn how to animate tableview.

**EDIT:**

Also you can refer to this tutorial to learn UIView Animation:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2454/how-to-use-uiview-animation-tutorial

**EDIT - 2:**

Here is a sample code for animations.

This is the code you should write on button click event, which you use to show the table view:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

tableView.frame = tableViewFrame;
tableView.hidden = NO;

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

This is the code you should write on tableView's delegate `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method. This code is to be written after you assign the selected value to your `NSUserDefault` or your variable, which is supposed to hold the selected tableView cell value.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
tableView.hidden = YES;

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

HTH.

Comment: Can you give me some sample code with which I can do animations/ i have no idea

Comment: @KhushbuShah: I have already added link to my answer. Please check.

Comment: @KhushbuShah: Please check the **EDIT - 2** section of my answer. It contains code for the animations of the table view. Also I suggest to show the table View as a popover view.

Comment: @KhushbuShah: Why you asked me to post the whole code for animation, when you are not going to use this answer?

Comment: @parth-i got that answer before yours yaar. and really your code helped me i my work .But stack has not given option to tick more than 1 answers . Sorry :(

Comment: @KhushbuShah: Its ok Relax :-)

Answer (score 0):

NSString *title = @"click";
    NSArray *indexarr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",nil];

```
NSDictionary*dic1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"one" forKey:@"1"];
NSDictionary*dic2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"two" forKey:@"2"];    
NSDictionary*dic3 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"three" forKey:@"3"];

NSArray *conntarr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:dic1,dic2,dic3,nil];

NSDictionary *dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:title,@"title",indexarr,@"index",conntarr,@"content",nil];
sleep(2);
return dic;
```

it can be use to open popup on button click....